# Memory allocation for arrays

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management

As I now, memory allocation for new array is "object size according to his type" * "length". While reading, we are going to "start array index + object size * position".

If we have an array A[], we can put object of type B in to this array if "B extends A". But size of object "new B" can be different, that object of type A. How does it work? Java store links for non-primitive arrays?

Comment: Why should the object size matter? This is not C or whatever. An array doesn't actually store an object in each index, it uses references.

Comment: Correct formula would be `(pointer size according to system architecture) * (array size) + (some constant overhead for metainformation)`.

Comment: *"Java store links for non-primitive arrays?"* - Yes.  But the correct term is a *reference* rather than a link.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Looks like I had a wrong information about java arrays. Thanks